# CakePHP Validate data from an associated model in the controller

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-model

Hello, basically I have two models: **User** and **Profile**. Each User **hasOne** Profile.

So, when I submit the Form, it should validate as follows:

```php
/* UsersController.php */

...

if ($this->request -> isPost()) {
    $this->loadModel('Profile'); //By some reason I have to use loadModel, even if I include it on App::uses
    $this->Profile->set( $this->request->data );
    $validates = $this->Profile->validateAssociated($this->request->data['Profile']);

    if($validates){
        //do kinky stuff
    } else {
        //cry
    }
```

I defined the `$validate` rules on the Profile Model generated in bake.

I've tried different approaches, with no success:

```php
    $this->Profile->set( $this->request->data );
    if($this->Profile->validates()){
        //do kinky stuff
    } else {
        //cry
    }
```

Every time it goes straight and throws me a SQL Error.

Any ideas? Am I missing something?

***EDIT:***

Here's the Validation rules (I re-baked the rules to ensure that they were correctly formatted):

```php
public $validate = array(
    'twitter' => array(
        'custom' => array(
            'rule'  => array('custom','([A-Za-z0-9_]+)'),
            'message'  => 'S&oacute;lo son admitidos letras, n&uacute;meros y guiones al piso'
        ),
    ),
    'facebook_id' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            'message' => 'Ingrese su nombre en Facebook'
        ),
    ),
    'country_id' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            'message' => 'Seleccione un pa&iacute;s'
        ),
    ),
    'state_id' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            'message' => 'Seleccione un departamento'
        ),
    ),
    'city_id' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            'message' => 'Seleccione una ciudad'
        ),
    ),
    'barrio' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            'message' => 'Ingrese un barrio'
        ),
    ),
    'direccion' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            'message' => 'Ingrese una direcci&oacute;n'
        ),
    ),
    'telefono' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            'message' => 'Ingrese un tel&eacute;fono'
        ),
        'numeric' => array(
            'rule' => array('numeric'),
            'message' => 'S&oacute;lo se admiten n&uacute;meros.'
        ),
    ),
    'celular' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            'message' => 'Ingrese un celular'
        ),
        'numeric' => array(
            'rule' => array('numeric'),
            'message' => 'S&oacute;lo se admiten n&uacute;meros.'
        ),
    ),
    'nacimiento' => array(
        'date' => array(
            'rule' => array('date'),
            'message' => 'Ingrese una fecha de nacimiento v&aacute;lida.'
        ),
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            'message' => 'Ingrese una fecha de nacimiento.'
        ),
    ),
    'sexo' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            'message' => 'Seleccione sexo'
        ),
    ),
    'estado_civil' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            'message' => 'Seleccione estado civil'
        ),
    ),
    'estrato' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            'message' => 'Seleccione estrato'
        ),
    ),
    'estudio_id' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            'message' => 'Seleccione nivel de estudios'
        ),
    ),
    'ocupacion_id' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            'message' => 'Seleccione ocupaci&oacute;n'
        ),
    ),
    'personas_casa' => array(
        'comparison' => array(
            'rule' => array('comparison', '>', 0),
            'message' => 'Seleccione el n&uacute;mero de personas en la casa'
        ),
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            'message' => 'Seleccione el n&uacute;mero de personas en la casa'
        ),
    ),
    'referred_by' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            'message' => 'Seleccione c&oacute;mo se enter&oacute; de la Comunidad Talk'
        ),
    ),
    'referrer' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            'message' => 'Seleccione c&oacute;mo se enter&oacute; de la Comunidad Talk'
        ),
    ),
);
```

And the error (which states that the validation was skipped):

```php
Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'country_id' cannot be null

SQL Query: INSERT INTO `newTalk`.`profiles` (`user_id`, `twitter`, `facebook_id`, `country_id`, `state_id`, `city_id`, `barrio`, `direccion`, `codigo_postal`, `telefono`, `celular`, `nacimiento`, `sexo`, `estado_civil`, `estrato`, `estudio_id`, `ocupacion_id`, `personas_casa`, `referred_by`, `modified`, `created`) VALUES (2, '', '', NULL, NULL, NULL, '', '', '', '', '', NULL, '0', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NULL, '2012-06-28 12:56:07', '2012-06-28 12:56:07')
```

Comment: Can you post your validation rules for Profile and the SQL error you get?

Comment: I don't understand. Is the problem with your validation rules or with the array you pass in to validateAssociated? Can you verify?

Comment: @swiecki I think that the problem is with the controller, the validation was broken before, but I corrected the rules and it worked... but then it stopped working :-/

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing your form has posted both User and Profile data.

In the second example you're using the wrong format for set().

Form the manual

```
<?php
$this->Post->read(null, 1);
$this->Post->set(array(
    'title' => 'New title',
    'published' => false
));
$this->Post->save();
?>
```

You could try:

```
$this->Profile->set($this->request->data["Profile"])
if($this->Profile->validates()) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: No, the `validates()` is returning true :-/ (BTW I've also tried this)

Answer (score 0):

The minor thing to remember, if you are validating your associated model data. Then all the related fields should contain in that Model named array.